# Why my solution is wrong for Rainbow Array question on codechef?

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying out Rainbow array question on code chef:
[question](https://www.codechef.com/problems/RAINBOWA) in Java.
 My solution passes all the three test cases as mentioned in the question but I dont understand why my [solution](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/22577318) is not accepted.
[image: screen shot]. Please let me know what modifications shall I make and why?

**Chef and Rainbow Array**

Chef likes all arrays equally. But he likes some arrays more equally than others. In particular, he loves Rainbow Arrays.

An array is Rainbow if it has the following structure:

1. First a1 elements equal 1.
2. Next a2 elements equal 2.
3. Next a3 elements equal 3.
4. Next a4 elements equal 4.
5. Next a5 elements equal 5.
6. Next a6 elements equal 6.
7. Next a7 elements equal 7.
8. Next a6 elements equal 6.
9. Next a5 elements equal 5.
10. Next a4 elements equal 4.
11. Next a3 elements equal 3.
12. Next a2 elements equal 2.
13. Next a1 elements equal 1.
14. ai can be any non-zero positive integer.
15. There are no other elements in array.

**Input**

- The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases.
- The first line of each test case contains an integer N, denoting the number of elements in the given array.
- The second line contains N space-separated integers A1, A2, ..., AN denoting the elements of array.

**Output**

- For each test case, output a line containing "yes" or "no" (without quotes) corresponding to the case if the array is rainbow array or not.

**Constraints**

- 1 ≤ T ≤ 100
- 7 ≤ N ≤ 100
- 1 ≤ Ai ≤ 10

**Subtasks**
Subtask 1 (100 points) : Original constraints

**Example**

**Input**

3

19

1 2 3 4 4 5 6 6 6 7 6 6 6 5 4 4 3 2 1

14

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 1

13

1 2 3 4 5 6 8 6 5 4 3 2 1

**Output**

yes

no

no

My solution:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Codechef
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int T=sc.nextInt();
    while(T-->0)
    {
        int N=sc.nextInt();

        int A[]=new int[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            A[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        int flag=0;
        //taking the length to iterate over upto the half if the array
        int len;
        if(N%2==0) {
            len=N/2;
        }
        else {
            len=(N/2)+1;
        }
        //Condition 1: palandrome or nor
        //Condition 2: 7 present or not
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if(A[i]!=A[N-1-i] || A[len-1]!=7) {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println("Flag: "+flag);

        if(flag==0) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }else {
            System.out.println("no");
        }

    }


  }
 }
```

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: also post the actual question here. we shouldn't have to go visit some external link just so we can find out what it is you are trying to do

Comment: @CodeMatrix I have added my solution .

Comment: @Stultuske I have added the question along with solution